# Получить все данные с input'тов с одним именем

Tags: jquery

Есть несколько `input`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="hello" id="txt"/>
<input type="hidden" value="10" id="count" />

<input type="hidden" value="hello world" id="txt"/>
<input type="hidden" value="12" id="count" />
```

Как из них получить значения в виде: `var str = hello*10\hello world*12`?

http://jsfiddle.net/rpv9yp7u/

Comment: У вас у двух инпутов одинаковый айдишник. Так делать нельзя, и чего Вы хотите - мне непонятно.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rpv9yp7u/ Тут идет в виде `{"hello":["hello","hello world"],"count":["10","12"]}` а как вывести это в виде ` hello*10\hello world*12`

Answer (score 1):

### Ваши ошибки

1. Ваши инпуты с разными именами, точнее вообще без имен. Имя это атрибут name.
2. Ваши инпуты одного типа - **hidden**
3. Нельзя присваивать разным элементам одинаковые **id**. Не при при каких условиях нельзя. Если очень хочется, то используйте классы. `class='txt'`

### Решение №1

Присваиваем разные **id**

```
<input type="hidden" value="hello" id="txt1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="10" id="count1" />

<input type="hidden" value="hello world" id="txt2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="12" id="count2" />

var txt1 = $('#txt1').val()
var count1= $('#count1').val()
var txt2= $('#txt2').val()
var count2= $('#count2').val()
```

### Решение №2

Обернуть группы инпутов в объединяющей тэг.

```
<div id='block1'>
    <input type="hidden" value="hello" class="txt"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="10" class="count" />
</div>

<div id='block2'>
    <input type="hidden" value="hello" class="txt"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="10" class="count" />
</div>

var txt1 = $('#block1 > .txt').val()
var count1 = $('#block1 > .count').val()
var txt2= $('#block2 > .txt').val()
var count2= $('#block2 > .count').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос если кому надо:

```js
function getvalues(){
var inps = document.getElementsByName('count[]');
var tovar = document.getElementsByName('tovar[]');
var set = [];
for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
var inp=inps[i];
var tov = tovar[i];
set.push(tov.value + "*" + inp.value);
}
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = set;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="tovar[]" value="m4" />
<input type="text" name="count[]" value="10" />
<br>
<input type="text" name="tovar[]" value="ak"/>
<input type="text" name="count[]" value="12" /><br>
<input type="button" value="get it!" onclick="getvalues();" />

<div id="div1"></div>
```